# Reference for poor sampler mixing in large bayesian models

Tags: bayesian, sampling, nonparametric

I keep seeing this in various presentations, but never saw a reference for it. Although it makes an intuitive sense why samplers potentially can face mixing issue when operating on large space of possibilities (i.e., in large Bayesian models), I wonder if there is a text book, or an article for this to cite?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "large space of possibilities" do you mean when you have a large number of parameters to estimate?  The basic issue there is that probability densities get weird in high dimensions: specifically the density becomes too spread out and a sampler has a hard time coping.  Michael Betancourt has a [nice introduction to Hamiltonian MCMC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02434.pdf) that also deals conceptually with some of the problems with MCMC in high-dim settings in the first few sections.  If you want more specifics you might also look at general discussions of [probability in high dimensions](https://www.princeton.edu/~rvan/ORF570.pdf), although you'll need to think about how this intersects with the behavior of an MCMC sampler.